# How to create a parallelepiped tiling?

Tags: graphics3d

I know how to create parallelepiped and combine them to form a parallelepiped tiling, but the tiles overlap...

I started with this code:

```
P1 = Graphics3D[{GeometricTransformation[{Opacity[.85], Red, 
     Cuboid[]}, ShearingMatrix[Pi/4, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}]]}, 
  Boxed -> False]   

P2 = Graphics3D[{GeometricTransformation[{Opacity[.85], Red, 
     Cuboid[]}, ShearingMatrix[Pi/4, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}]]}, 
  Boxed -> False]

P3 = Graphics3D[{GeometricTransformation[{Opacity[.85], Red, 
     Cuboid[]}, ShearingMatrix[Pi/4, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}]]}, 
  Boxed -> False]

Show[P1,P2,P3]
```

[image]

I don't know how to fix the positions of the parallelepipeds (I prefer different shapes) so that they will not overlap and no gaps between them.

Comment: Your parallelepipeds are all the same, which is why they overlap. To tile them, you need to also translate them in x/y/z, depending on how your tiling arrangement is. As an example starting with your `P1`: `Graphics3D[
 NestList[GeometricTransformation[#, 
    TranslationTransform[{1/2, 3/2, 0}]] &, First@P1, 5], 
 Boxed -> False]` Istvan's answer shows a better way to build up the tiles.

Answer (score 4):

Tiling of a plane in 3D:

```
para = Table[
   GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[{i, j, k}], 
      ShearingMatrix[Pi/4, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}]],
   {i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, 3}, {k, 0, 0}];

c = 0;
Graphics3D[{Opacity@.85, Map[{Hue[c = c + .03], #} &, para, {2}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Tiling of a volume:

```
para = Table[
   GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[{i, j, k}], 
    ShearingMatrix[Pi/4, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}]],
   {i, 0, 5}, {j, 0, 3}, {k, 0, 2}];

Graphics3D[{Opacity@.85, Map[{Hue@RandomReal[], #} &, para, {3}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's not that hard to play around with coordinates to get a mirrir-tiling:

```
para = Table[
   GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[{i, 0, k}], 
    ShearingMatrix[Pi/4, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}]], {i, 0, 5}, {k, 0, 1}];
para2 = Table[
   GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[{1, j - 4, k}], 
    ShearingMatrix[-Pi/4, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}]], {j, 0, 5}, {k, 0, 1}];

Graphics3D@{para, para2}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much... But what if I want the parallelepiped to distinct? Thanks again^_^

Comment: @Sey What do you mean by distinct? Color?

Comment: I mean distinct shapes of parallelepipeds, similar to
3D Rep-Tiles and Irreptiles.

Thanks so much

Comment: @Sey An image or a more formal description would help to understand what you really want because at the moment I'm clueless.

Comment: @Istvan-Thanks so much for your willingness to help.

A patch of such a tiling is shown below.


   
   }
  ]]

The one you made comprises of copies of a parallelepiped, but i want the parallelepiped to have different shapes but still fill the 3D plane - no overlaps and no gaps between them...

I can actually create just using lines, but seems to be tiring...Thanks so much

Comment: Graphics3D[Line[{
   
   {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, -1}}, {{0, 2, -1}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{1, 2, -1}, {1, 
     1, 0}}, {{1, 1, -1}, {1, 0, 0}},
   
   {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 
     2}},
   {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 2}} , 
   {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 2, 
     2}},
   {{0, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 2}}, {{0, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}},
   {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {0, 2, 2}}}]]